# Simplifying requires/imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS right now and trying to separate all the components into discrete files.

Is there some strategy to simplify the process of requiring/importing components? It seems rather silly to have `import React from 'react';` on the first line of every component file?

I'm using Babel for the `import` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around writing `import React from 'react'` every time, you can use Webpack and:

1. write a loader that adds the statement `import React from 'react'` to every JSX file it encounters; or,
2. use React from a CDN and include it as a Webpack external in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's the recommended way if you want to use the import/export mechanism from ES6 to separate the component.
A way to not do this is to assign React as a global variable, but that kinda defeat the purpose of using import/export.

Indeed we need to do similar things in other languages like Java?